# Graphics NullPointerException when overriding Canvas paint method inline

Tags: java, canvas, awt

So I'm attempting to create a Canvas, and override the paint method inline, however I'm getting a NullPointerException on the Canvas' Graphics.

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(){
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Canvassed Window", 100, 100);
    }
};
```

NullPointerException comes for

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I'm just going to create a new class that inherits from Canvas, but I was wondering if anyone knew the reason that it was doing this. I have a suspicion that it's because the Canvas hasn't been initialised yet.

I also wondered if anyone knew a workaround for it, I tried to write something that looked like

```
private boolean isInit = false;
init(){
    isInit = true;
}
```

and then in the paint method put a line in there at the top that says

```
if(!isInit) return;
```

but when I tried to call init later on it didn't want to know, it just errored and said that init wasn't in the Canvas class, I'm guessing that I can only override methods in this manner.

EDIT:

I have a Window class

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Frame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Window extends Frame{

    public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY) {
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocation(locationX, locationY);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Window");
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY, String title){
        Window w = new Window(width, height, locationX, locationY);
        w.setTitle(title);
    }
    public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY, String title, Canvas c){
        Window w = new Window(width, height, locationX, locationY, title);
        w.add(c);
    }

}
```

And here's my main method, where I create a new Window instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Canvas c = new Canvas(){
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Canvassed Window", 100, 100);
        }
    };
    new Window(800, 600, 200, 100, "CanvassedWindow", c);
}
```

I'm getting a Window or "Frame" come up, right size, dimensions and title, however it does not seem to be drawing the String, and there's an NPE. I'm not doing anything else, all I have is a wrapper class for my main method.

Comment: There's more to your problem and your code than you're showing us. This code should not throw a NPE unless it's being used in a strange way. Also as a side question, why AWT and not Swing?

Comment: Please show us a minimum working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: How are you calling `paint()`?

Comment: @codeNinja: he shouldn't be directly calling the `paint()` method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm using AWT for work. Decided to educate myself on it.

Comment: So work is using AWT in preference over Swing? Amazing. Well regardless, please tell us the rest of the problem, the information that will allow us to answer your question without providing SWAGs.

Comment: AWT is 15 years out of date, it was replaced by Swing over 15 years ago, yes some understanding of how AWT works can help, but I wouldn't be my first point of call. Are you using getGraphics and trying to call paint yourself?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: he's doing something wrong that he's not telling or showing us despite our multiple attempts to get the information out of him.

Comment: You have a constructor creating an instance of itself, which is very dangerous code, and so your code creates **two** windows. I'm pretty sure that you don't want to do what you're doing. Perhaps you mean to call `this(...)` instead to call the more default constructor. Your code should **not** cause the NPE that you're describing, and so the mystery continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on you example, the `Window` class will create three new windows, of which, only one is visible, and not the one your adding your `Canvas` to...

When you call `new Window(800, 600, 200, 100, "CanvassedWindow", c);`, this creates a new instance of `Window` (`JFrame`), this is window #1, but it is not visible...

The `public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY, String title, Canvas c)` constructor then creates another instance of `Window` (`JFrame`), this is window #2, but it is not visible...

This then calls `public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY, String title)`, which creates another `Window`, which is actually the one that is visible...

This is because the constructor `Window w = new Window(width, height, locationX, locationY);` is the only one which actually sets the frame's properties and makes it visible...

This is probably leading down some weird paths...it certainly did for me...

Instead, you should be chaining your constructors, for example...

```
public class Window extends Frame{

    public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY) {
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocation(locationX, locationY);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Window");
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY, String title){
        this(width, height, locationX, locationY);
        setTitle(title);
    }
    public Window(int width, int height, int locationX, int locationY, String title, Canvas c){
        this(witdth, height, locationX, locationY, title);
        add(c);
    }

}
```